# How to improve this OrientDB query for max performance?

Tags: performance, orientdb, orientdb2.2

Orient Graph DB has 33 million records(Vertex - 18million and Edge - 15million records).

I would like to know whether the problem in my query or is it because of Orient DB.

Im using

**DB** : OrientDB 2.2.30 with all default configurations.

**CPU** : Intel Core i5 3rd gen (Quad Core)

**RAM** : 8 GB

Each class has records in 4 clusters.

If I execute below query1, it takes 20s - 35s and query-2 takes 100s to 350s to execute.

**Query1:**

`SELECT EXPAND(OUT('EpochTimeToLogData')) FROM EpochTime WHERE UnixTime = 1525000000`

**Query2:**

`SELECT * FROM LogData WHERE @rid IN (SELECT OUT('EpochTimeToLogData')[0] FROM EpochTime WHERE UnixTime = 1525000000)`

Comment: Hi have you tried using indexes? You can take a look at this link for more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Indexes.html